# Google Sheet - Dynamically change graph bar colour trough a Sheet list

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, graph

I'm trying to read from column T of my sheet colour that i want to apply to each 2nd series of my graph.

I'm trying different solution:
if i get Value from a single cell and than I apply to option  it works. But I would read 100 values copying the same instruction in the code

I wish to create an array (I did) of colour and than apply with a for cycle to each bar of the graph.

Here below the code

```
 function updateColor2() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var ws = ss.getActiveSheet();
var charts = ws.getCharts();
var chart = charts[0];
var id = chart.getId();
var colour= ws.getRange('T9:T13').getValues()
//var colour =[];
//var colour = ws.getRange(9, 20).getValue();//
Logger.log(colour);
chart = chart.modify()

//for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
 //var colour =[];
 //colour.push(ws.getRange(i+9,20).getValue();
             
.setOption('series.2.items.0.color', colour[0])
.setOption('series.2.items.1.color', colour[1])
.setOption('series.2.items.2.color', colour[2])
.setOption('series.2.items.3.color', colour[3])
.setOption('series.2.items.4.color', colour[4])
 //            }
.build();
ws.updateChart(chart);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Dynamically add options to chart:

Add an additional option to your graph in each iteration of your loop via [modify()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/embedded-chart#modify()), and build it again via [build()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/embedded-chart-builder#build()) **inside the iteration**, like this:

```
for (let i = 0; i < colour.length; i++) {
  chart = chart.modify()
               .setOption('series.2.items.' + i + '.color', colour[i])
               .build();
}
```

In this sample, the loop counter (`i`) is used to identify for the item index from the `series` and the color index from `colour`.

#### Note:

- While this is not necessary, it would be appropriate to transform `colour` into a simple array ([getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues()) returns a 2D array) so that each colour passed in `.setOption` is a string value and not an array with a single element. You can use [flat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) to achieve this:

```
var colour= ws.getRange('T9:T13').getValues().flat();
```

Comment: Thank you it worked properly! I had just to add a little modification while the code dind't stop running. `for (let i=0;i<=cl;i++){`

Comment: @PaoloMesolella Sorry, that was a typo on my part, just fixed it (`i < colour.length`). Also, would you consider [accepting and upvoting this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)? This is useful because this community relies on it to share knowledge to other users.